# Presenting an optimal route solution using a tikz graph

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm intending to conduct a mathematical optimization problem where my solution is to be presented graphically. For this I've tried to form a graph in `tikz` using nodes and edges between these. My code this far is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
            petri,%
            topaths}%
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage[position=top]{subfig}
\begin{document}

\centering
\twocolumn

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,transform shape]
\SetGraphUnit{4}
\tikzset{
  VertexStyle/.append style={
  bend angle    = 45,%
  fill          = gray!30
 }  
}
\Vertex{21}
\NOEA(21){31}
\SOEA(21){52}
\NOEA(31){41}
\SOEA(31){62}
\SOEA(62){72}
\tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[pre and post]
\Edge[label=$4$](21)(52)
\Edge[label=$9$](52)(62)
\Edge[label=$8$](21)(31)
\Edge[label=$7$](31)(41)
\Edge[label=$3$](62)(72)
\Edge[label=$1$](52)(31)
\Edge[label=$10$](41)(62)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have two questions however:

1. Is there a way of making the graph as presented in the picture which illustrates the flow of the solution and
2. How to make this picture somewhat smaller, so it can be used in for instance a `\twocolumn` solution?

[image: Sought-after solution]

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Comment: \draw[blue,thick,->] (41) to[bend left,midway] node[fill=white]{$t=1$} (62); (for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the curved arrows, you can simply add some regular drawing commands at the end of the picture. The `quotes` library makes adding the labels easy:

```
  \draw [blue,->]
    (41) edge ["+=1",bend left]  (62)
    (62) edge ["+=2", bend left] (72)
    ;
  \draw [red,->]
    (21) edge ["+=1",bend left]  (31)
    (31) edge ["+=2", bend left] (21)
    (21) edge ["+=3", bend right, swap] (52)
    (52) edge ["+=4", bend right, swap] (62)
    ;
```

[image: arrows]

As for making it fit. Well, you can make it smaller by adjusting the `scale` factor downwards. For example using `0.625` rather than `0.75` and showing the frame of the page:

[image: shrink-to-fit]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage,showframe,kantlipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,petri,quotes}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn
{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.625,transform shape]
  \SetGraphUnit{4}
  \tikzset{
    VertexStyle/.append style={
      bend angle    = 45,
      fill          = gray!30
    }
  }
  \Vertex{21}
  \NOEA(21){31}
  \SOEA(21){52}
  \NOEA(31){41}
  \SOEA(31){62}
  \SOEA(62){72}
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style=pre and post}
  \Edge[label=$4$](21)(52)
  \Edge[label=$9$](52)(62)
  \Edge[label=$8$](21)(31)
  \Edge[label=$7$](31)(41)
  \Edge[label=$3$](62)(72)
  \Edge[label=$1$](52)(31)
  \Edge[label=$10$](41)(62)
  \draw [blue,->]
    (41) edge ["+=1",bend left]  (62)
    (62) edge ["+=2", bend left] (72)
    ;
  \draw [red,->]
    (21) edge ["+=1",bend left]  (31)
    (31) edge ["+=2", bend left] (21)
    (21) edge ["+=3", bend right, swap] (52)
    (52) edge ["+=4", bend right, swap] (62)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}\par}
\kant[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I've tested this now and it works perfectly. Sometimes even LaTeX surprises you how beautiful graphs become in it :)

Comment: @GustavDanell Glad it helped. I know nothing about the `tkz-` stuff because I can't read the documentation :(.